# Memory allocation for Pointer

Tags: pointers, memory, memory-management

> **In which section memory is allocated if I write something like**

```
1. int *ptr;
   *ptr = 22;

 2. int *ptr = new int(22);
```

What I Understand is when we use keyword new then memory is get reserved into Heap and that reserved memory address is get returned .

But what happened in case we didn't use keyword new ?? Where memory is get allocated ??

is Both Syntax is Same ?? If No, what is Exact difference between these two statement ??

Comment: `int* ptr = 22;` would, I guess, interpret `22` as a pointer if it compiled. That probably wouldn’t point to valid memory and certainly wouldn’t reserve it.

Comment: Ok Silly mistake . But what if it is Just like int *ptr .

Comment: No extra memory is allocated when you just declare a pointer; it’s like any other variable. An `int num;`, for example, would have space reserved for it (maybe on the stack, maybe not); `int* ptr;` is the same.

Answer (score 2):

You code examples can be rephrased as follows:

1st:

```
int * ptr;
*ptr = 22;
```

2nd:

```
int * ptr;
ptr = new int; //the only difference
*ptr = 22;
```

What happens in the second one:

1. `int * ptr;` means create variable capable of storing address of int variable. For now variable isn't initialized, so it stores garbage. If you interpret garbage as pointer, it can points anywhere (it can be 0, or 0xabcdef11, or 0x31323334, or literally ANYTHING which is left on non-cleared memory form previous usage)
2. `ptr = new int;` means "allocate memory area capable of holding int and store its address in ptr variable". Since this line, ptr points to specific memory
3. `*ptr = 22;` means put value 22 to memory pointed by ptr.

In the first example you create variable, but don't initialize it. `ptr` contains garbage, but you ask to interpret it as address and store 22 to this address. What can happen:

- address is invalid (e.g. 0, or out of address range, or points to protected memory) => program crashes
- address is valid and writable, but memory area is used by another part of the program: you'll write 22, but it will corrupt someone's data, result totally unpredictable.
- address is valid and writable, memory area isn't in use. You'll write 22, but you aren't guaranteed to read it back. Memory can become used for different purpose and 22 will be overwritten.
- anything else. All this is actually an undefined behavior, everything is possible.

That's why it's always recommended to initialize pointer immediately:

```
int * ptr = NULL; //or better "nullptr" starting from C++11
```

Attempt to store value `*ptr = 22;` will at least explicitly crash the program.